# How to get the text after grep regex match?

Tags: bash, grep

I am new to bash and I want to make a script which will be translating words to another languages. I have a dictionary file in which I have sentences like *Rower pte Bicycle*. Every sentence has another line. What I try to do is to find a match using grep:

```
if eval 'nohup grep "'$arg1' '$arg2' [A-Za-z]\+" /tmp/dict.txt > /dev/null'; then
    echo 'found match'
else
```

I am getting a *found match* response, but I need the word (or string) after the match (arg1 is Rower and arg2 is pte). I want to get *Bicycle* and put it into script variable.

I also have a problem with some regex I have found on stack. It looks like this:

```
sed -n -e 's!.*en.wikipedia.org/wiki/\(.*\)" title.*!\1!p'
```

Can anyone explain me this regex code or provide the schema of decripting it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if eval 'nohup grep "'$arg1' '$arg2' [A-Za-z]\+" /tmp/dict.txt > /dev/null'; then
    echo 'found match'
else
```

If you look closely, you are sending the standard output of grep to `/dev/null` (i.e. the bit-bucket/no man's land). To see the result of the grep command, change `> /dev/null` to `2> /dev/null` (which will only send `stderr` to `/dev/null`) **or** remove the redirect to `/dev/null` altogether (e.g. get rid of `> /dev/null`). Just be aware you will see all `grep` output in that case.

Second, to get only the words that follow `arg1` and `arg2`, you will have to assign the results of `grep` to a variable and parse to eliminate the text up to `arg2`, or pipe it and parse it directly.

```
sed -n -e 's!.*en.wikipedia.org/wiki/\(.*\)" title.*!\1!p'
```

Is a simple `sed regex` where the normal separators `/` have been replaced by `!` to prevent conflict with the `/` in the URL. It simply says find the string `en.wikipedia.org/wiki/` **save** what follows **between** `\(...\)` up to the last `" title` and then replace that mess with only what was **saved** (presumably the last part of the URL --or-- pagename). Using the **saved** part of the expression in the replacement part of the substitution is called a `back reference`. This is what `\1` accomplishes. You can use more that one grouping and `back reference` with `\2`, etc..